# How to specify @Throws for a property in interface

Tags: java, kotlin, rmi

I am currently porting some Java RMI code to Kotlin. The legacy interface in Java is:

```
interface Foo: Remote {
    Bar getBar() throws RemoteException
}
```

After running the auto-migration tool, the field `bar` is changed into a property:

```
interface Foo: Remote {
    val bar: Bar
}
```

However, in the migrated program, `getBar` is no longer marked as `throws RemoteException`, which causes `illegal remote method encountered` error in a RMI call.

I was wondering is there any way to mark `@Throws` for a property?

Comment: Prefer functions over properties when the method throws.

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site/blob/yole/styleguide/pages/docs/reference/coding-conventions.md#functions-vs-properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you look at [`@Throws`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/index.html):

If there is a specific getter that does not use the backing field, simply annotate it directly:

```
val bar: Bar
    @Throws(RemoteException::class) get() = doSomething()
```

The valid targets for `@Throws` are

```
AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER,
AnnotationTarget.CONSTRUCTOR
```

So in other cases, you need to target the getter itself and not the property:

```
@get:Throws(RemoteException::class)
```

> [The full list of supported use-site targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) is:
>
> - file;
> - property (annotations with this target are not visible to Java);
> - field;
> - get (property getter);
> - set (property setter);
> - receiver (receiver parameter of an extension function or property);
> - param (constructor parameter);
> - setparam (property setter parameter);
> - delegate (the field storing the delegate instance for a delegated property).

`@get` specifies that this annotation will be applied to the getter.

Your full interface would be

```
interface Foo: Remote {
    @get:Throws(RemoteException::class)
    val bar: Bar
}
```

Here's a problem though - in the generated code, there *is* no `throws` clause generated. I feel like this may be a bug, as the annotation is clearly marked as targeting these four use-sites. `CONSTRUCTOR` and `FUNCTION` definitely work, it's just the property ones that have none generated.

---

I took a look at the Kotlin compiler trying to find a possible reason, and I found [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/25d2cc02794dce8b8a18f809b2f566830ba63943/compiler/daemon/daemon-common/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/daemon/common/ReplStateFacade.kt):

```
interface ReplStateFacade : Remote {

    @Throws(RemoteException::class)
    fun getId(): Int

    ...
}
```

Which interestingly avoids properties in order to use `@Throws`.
Maybe this is a known workaround?

Comment: So, how should the interface be written?

Comment: `@get:Throws(exception types)` should annotate the property

Comment: 1. Why don't you write the complete code in your answer? Note though that it doesn't seem to work here: If I do that and try calling Foo.getBar() from Java code, the compiler doesn't force me to handle RemoteException.

Comment: @JBNizet I am aware of this and believe this is could be a bug. The `get` target is clearly the getter method, and yet strangely no throws clause is generated. All other targets work (`FUNCTION`, `CONSTRUCTOR`), I tried it myself and am trying to take a closer look at this.