# @Throws has no effect when the target is a property

Tags: java, annotations, jvm, kotlin, throws

While taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47737288/7366707), I noticed that applying `@Throws` to a `get` or `set` use-site has no effect.

Additionally, *the only valid targets* for `@Throws` are `AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION`, `AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER`, `AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER`, and `AnnotationTarget.CONSTRUCTOR`.

Other annotations, such as the JPA annotations and `Deprecated` work fine and are properly applied to the method!

This is strange behavior.

To demonstrate, I created a simple abstract class in Java, with one constructor, one method and one get method.

```
public abstract class JavaAbstractClass {

    @Deprecated
    @NotNull public abstract String getString() throws IOException;
    public abstract void setString(@NotNull String string) throws IOException;

    public abstract void throwsFunction() throws IOException;

    public JavaAbstractClass() throws IOException {
    }

}
```

As you can see, every method/constructor is marked as throwing `IOException`.

However, when I try to write an equivalent class in Kotlin, and mark the appropriate methods with `throws` for interop, the generated `getString` and `setString` methods have no `throws` clause.

```
abstract class KotlinAbstractClass @Throws(IOException::class) constructor() {

    @get:Deprecated("Deprecated")
    @get:Throws(IOException::class)
    @set:Throws(IOException::class)
    abstract var string: String

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    abstract fun throwsFunction()

}
```

The decompiled code:

```
@Metadata(Some metadata here)
public abstract class KotlinAbstractClass {
   /** @deprecated */
   @Deprecated(
      message = "Deprecated"
   ) // @Deprecated made it through!
   @NotNull
   public abstract String getString(); // Nothing here!

   public abstract void setString(@NotNull String var1); // Nothing here!

   public abstract void throwsFunction() throws IOException;

   public KotlinAbstractClass() throws IOException {
   }
}
```

To me, it seems to be because these internal annotations must be handled specially by the compiler, instead of being applied directly to the method.

Additionally, applying it to the getter of a non-abstract property:

```
val string: String
@Throws(IOException::class) get() = "Foo"
```

*does* generate a method with the signature `public final String getString() throws IOException`!

Perhaps this case wasn't handled properly?

Is this a bug?

---

Note: This doesn't have anything to do with whether the method actually throws this exception.

If I do:

```
@get:Throws(IOException::class)
val string: String
    get() = BufferedReader(FileReader("file.txt")).readText()
```

The compiled code is still

```
@NotNull
public final String getString() {
    return TextStreamsKt.readText((Reader)(new BufferedReader((Reader)(new FileReader("file.txt")))));
}
```

despite the fact that the [`FileReader` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader(java.io.File)) throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Additionally, this shouldn't matter for abstract methods anyway, as they can't have an implementation and still can have a `throws` clause.

If I do as [@tynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385212/tynn) suggests and add a concrete implementation:

```
class ConcreteClass : KotlinAbstractClass() {

    override val string: String
        get() = BufferedReader(FileReader("file.txt")).readText()

    ...

}
```

I still get the same result.

Comment: Try to implement a getter or setter actually throwing this exception. If your code is safe, you do not have to redeclare the `throws` declarations of what you override. Maybe _Kotlin_ is just clever with its `@Throws` annotation.

Comment: @tynn I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe @tynn suggests you do the following:

```
override val string: String
        @Throws(FileNotFoundException::class) get() = BufferedReader(FileReader("file.txt")).readText()
```

This should give you the proper Java version with `throws` in the signature. I guess the reasoning is that if you just do this:

```
@get:Throws(IOException::class)
val foo: String = "foo"
```

the compiler is smart enough to see that there's nothing in the getter that would throw an `IOException`, since you've never overridden it, so it won't produce the `throws` section. When the getter is overridden, the compiler has no way to know if the code you've supplied can throw, so it obeys the annotation and will always output the `throws` part.

**UPDATE**

The following seems to generate correct bytecode:

```
abstract class KotlinAbstractClass {

    abstract var string: String
        @Throws(IOException::class) get
        @Throws(IOException::class) set
}
```

After taking a closer look at it, I see no reason for `@get:Throws(IOException::class)` not to work in this case. You might file an issue on the YouTrack for Kotlin and see what the team members have to say about it.

Comment: No, I addressed both parts in my question, putting `@Throws` directly onto _any_ getter, even if it does not throw, adds a `throws` clause. Putting `@get:Throws` onto _any_ property (even if it _does_ throw) has no effect. If I do as you suggest and put `val string: String @Throws(IOException::class) get() = "Foo"`, "the compiler is smart enough to see that there's nothing in the getter that would throw an IOException" is impossible, because a throws clause is still generated.

Comment: Ooh, I had forgotten about that possibility. I agree that it seems like the use-site annotation should work, I'll do that when I can. Thanks!